# Ajax function working in IE but not Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have an ajax function is called when a form is completed. It is suppose to redirect to a certain page if there is a success for a failure. When I run the form in IE, it works perfectly but in Firefox, the page does not redirect at all. It just refreshes the page. Here is the ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "someURL",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "xml",
    data: params,
    success: function () { window.location = 'success_page.htm' },
    failure: function () { window.location = 'error_page.htm' }
});
```

Comment: What error is firefox giving?

Comment: Try using a full url.

Comment: I'm not getting an error. It doesn't redirect at all.

Comment: `$.ajax()` doesn't have a `failure` option. It instead uses `error`. You may also want to place `console.log(arguments)` inside the `error` callback so you can see the details of the error that's occurring. Is the `someURL` a valid XML file?

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's a minor mistake in your code: you are missing some semicolons:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "someURL",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "xml",
    data: params,
    success: function () { window.location = 'success_page.htm'; },
    failure: function () { window.location = 'error_page.htm'; }
});
```

If this still doesn't resolve your problem, then I would guess there is something wrong with your `params` variable. Could you show us the whole code?

Comment: [ASI](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.9) should already handle that without issue.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
window.location = '/error_page.htm'
```

Sometimes working with IE  I had the same problem, I use window.location.href instead of window.location